# How to conver url to subdomain using Python

Tags: python, url, subdomain

So I have a list of URLs in a `urls.txt` file containing URL like examples given below:

```
https://benetech.blogspot.com/2019/02/robin-seaman-agent-of-inclusion.html
https://nikpeachey.blogspot.com/2020/01/digital-tools-for-teachers-trainers.html
https://blogurls245.blogspot.com/
```

Now I want to convert all URLs of that urls.txt to the subdomain, like the example given below:

```
https://benetech.blogspot.com
https://nikpeachey.blogspot.com
https://blogurls245.blogspot.com
```

I tried to do it using the `TLD` module but being an extreme beginner into Python couldn't figure out!

It'd be great if someone could help me with this getting done via Python.

Comment: Could you add to the question, the steps you already tried, with a minimal example of the code that didn't worked, and the error you got ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`urllib.parse` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to parse the URL into its constituent parts and assemble it back together, omitting parts you're not interested in:

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit

url = 'https://benetech.blogspot.com/2019/02/robin-seaman-agent-of-inclusion.html'

base = urlunsplit(urlsplit(url)[:2] + ('', '', ''))
print(base)  # https://benetech.blogspot.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `urllib.parse` module from the standard library:

```
url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
url_parts.path = “”
url_parts.query = “”
url_parts.fragment = “”
domain_only_url = urllib.parse.urlunparse(url_parts)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: can't set attribute`

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

sample_url = 'https://benetech.blogspot.com/2019/02/robin-seaman-agent-of-inclusion.html'

parsed_url = urlparse(sample_url)
subdomain = f'{parsed_url.scheme}://{parsed_url.hostname}'

print(subdomain)
```

### Output:

https://benetech.blogspot.com

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```py
url = 'https://benetech.blogspot.com/2019/02/robin-seaman-agent-of-inclusion.html'

parts = url.split('/')

subdomain = parts[0] + '//' + parts[2]
```

`subdomain` will be --> https://benetech.blogspot.com

`split('/')` will split string to several parts with `/`.
i.e --> `'my/name/is/Amirreza'` will be --> `['my','name','is','Amirreza']`

Comment: URL are complicated to parse, never attempt to do that manually, use the appropriate library.